# Can Every Higher Order PDE be Written as a System of 1st Order PDEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

**Motivation**
A section on the Wikipedia page ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)) of ordinary differential equations states the following.

---

**Reduction to a 1st Order System**

Any differential equation of order $n$ $$F\left(x,y,y',y'',\ldots,y^{(n-1)}\right)=y^{(n)},\quad\quad\text{where}\quad\quad y=y(x)$$ can be written as a system of $n$ 1st order differential equations by defining a new family of unknown functions $$y_{i}=y^{(i-1)},$$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. The $n$-dimensional system of first-order coupled differential equations is then $$y_{1}'=y_{2},\qquad y_{2}'=y_{3},\qquad\ldots,\qquad y_{n-1}'=y_{n},\qquad y_{n}'=F(x,y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{n}).$$

---

Is there a similar technique that applies to PDEs where any higher order PDE can be written as a system of 1st order PDEs? Are there any recommended books on PDEs that describe/discuss such a technique?

Thanks, Jack.

Comment: The same trick works.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried the technique on a 2nd order homogenous PDE. Do you have any recommended books to this technique for PDEs?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know the PDE literature, though weirdly enough I did use the trick once.